# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 on virtualbox partition SCSI3(sda) format message

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, virtualbox

I dualbooted OS with windows as the main partition and linux as the "secondary partition", and a linux swap partition(7gb). However, when I am on the windows OS, I download virtualbox and an ubuntu 14.04 image and following the steps, and then after I click install, I get a message saying

" `the following partitions are going to be formatted:

    partition #1 of SCSI3(0,0,0)(sda) as ext4,

    partition #5 of SCSI3(0,0,0)(sda) as swap.`

I know that this message means my that linux OS and the swap partition will get deleted, but I do not want this. Help. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the VirtualBox file and not your real drive, it won't format your real Linux.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks, I was thinking the same thing but became hesitant when it showed the actual partitions